# Number to keep on adding in a while loop (C++)

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

int n = 100;

while (n > 50) {

cout << n << ", ";
--n;

}

cout << "DONE!";

system("PAUSE");

}
```

Basically, this program will put the integer in a while loop and keep on subtracting one until it reaches 50, but I want it to do the opposite. Instead of --n (which keeps on subtraction one from the value), I want it to add one.

Okay, so how would you do this with multiplication? Because **n isn't working...?

Comment: This may surprise you, but that'd be `++n`.

Comment: Genuinely laughing aloud at the above comment, Derek it might be worth having a quick google before doing a SO post, save some time :)

Comment: Doing `++n` as other's said will increment the value. But you will also need to change your condition in `while` or else just doing `++n` will go to an infinite loop. Change `n > 50` to `n < x` where `x` is the last number that you want.

Comment: This is far too basic and won't be a useful addition to this Q&A repository. You can find it very early on in your C++ book, which I encourage you to begin reading now.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 0;

while (n < 50) {
   cout << n << ", ";
   n++;
}
```